# JVM DLL not found but I can clearly see the file

Tags: python, java, jvm, homebrew, sutime

I installed openjdk with Homebrew on my Mac but then I run a python library (`sutime`) that uses Java, I run into this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] JVM DLL not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/17.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libjli.dylib
```

However, when I run

`ls /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/17.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/lib`

I can see my dlls here including the one it seemingly couldn't find **libjli.dylib**. I'm pretty lost on why my dll isn't being detected even though it is in the correct filepath.

Comment: The term “DLL” is normally used for Windows libraries. Besides that, when the message says that the **JVM** DLL was not found, why do you think, it searched for lib named “JLI”?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I don't know why it search for a lib named JLI, but I am using the zulu jre, and it's looking for the same file: `libjli.dylib`. No ideas, anyone?